# Cannot connect to docker container instance on Google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've created a docker automated build using a private github repository containing a web server running on port 8000. I can run it on my OSX box within a fedora 20 VM but when I try to run it using a Google Compute Engine container-optimized image it says the instance is running but I can't connect to it from the browser using the EXTERNAL_IP output by gcloud compute after it creates the instance.

A gist containing additional info is at https://gist.github.com/wrabbit-revisited/758551f4ae9636ea4a9e. Perhaps I'm just using the wrong IP address to access the server. I'm assuming that it's mapping port 8000 to port 80 in the instance.

Comment: The server process which is, hopefully, running within the automated build container outputs to stdout using the golang log() function on startup. I think it is unbuffered. I suspect the docker API used to launch the container has access to the stdout/stderr logs. If it is placing them somewhere in the GCE VM instance which hosts the docker container it might help to narrow the possibilities.

Comment: What do the docker daemon logs say?

Comment: the logs show that docker was unable to retrieve the automated build. I believe it is because the underlying github repository is private and docker recently changed its behavior such that automated builds based on private repositories are also private. The pull works if i manually do a docker login within the GCE VM first. I don't think GCE is doing a docker login.. if it is then it doesn't have enough information to submit the correct credentials.

Comment: if someone knows of a way to pull a private automated build in Google Compute Engine i think it would answer this question.

Comment: @DavidAiken - I can't get any traffic going between the host and container ports but it seems like you at least got this to work at some point in time. Can you maybe weigh in on what's missing in this sample: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-vm-guestbook-redis-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brendan Burns on the google+ google-containers had an answer very quickly. It is necessary to authenticate to docker before pulling the build.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/d9426f8848883033e771ba1e28f86f624612b0f5/docs/images.md#using-a-private-registry